# PHP - Trying to create an array seems to not work

Tags: php, arrays

This is the code:

```
function create_order_with_custom_products()
{
    $orderGenerator = new OrderGenerator();
    $orderGenerator->setCustomer(6907);

    $orderGenerator->createOrder(array(
        // Add configurable product
        array(
            'product' => 30151,
            'qty' => 1
        ), array(
            'product' => 30150,
            'qty' => 2
        ),
    ));
}
```

I have to create array with such structure:

```
        array(
            'product' => 30151,
            'qty' => 1
        ), array(
            'product' => 30150,
            'qty' => 2
        ),
```

I am trying to create an array with same structure like that:

```
foreach($ItemsInCart['productid'] as $key=>$value){
    $ProductId = $value;
    $ProductQty = $ItemsInCart["productqty"][$key];
    $product_id = $ProductId; // Replace id with your product id
    $qty = $ProductQty; // Replace qty with your qty

    $ItemsId[] = ['product' => $ProductId, 'qty' => $ProductQty];
}
```

This gives me result of:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [product] => 30143 [qty] => 1 ) [1] => Array (
>   [product] => 30144 [qty] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [product] => 30145
>   [qty] => 3 ) [3] => Array ( [product] => 30146 [qty] => 4 ) [4] =>
>   Array ( [product] => 30147 [qty] => 5 ) )

All i want to know is why this :

```
function create_order_with_custom_products()
{
    $orderGenerator = new OrderGenerator();
    $orderGenerator->setCustomer(6907);

    $orderGenerator->createOrder(array(
        // Add configurable product
        array(
            'product' => 30151,
            'qty' => 1
        ), array(
            'product' => 30150,
            'qty' => 2
        ),
    ));
}
```

Is not the same as this:

```
function create_order_with_custom_products()
{
    $orderGenerator = new OrderGenerator();
    $orderGenerator->setCustomer(6907);

    $orderGenerator->createOrder(array($ItemsId));
}
```

Why the second approach is not working, where is my mistake?

Comment: Replace `$ItemsId[]["product"] = $ProductId;             
        $ItemsId[]["qty"] = $ProductQty;` with `$ItemsId[] = ['product' => $ProductId,
            'qty' => $ProductQty];`

Comment: I have udated my question can you please check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is

```
$ItemsId = []; //declaration
$ItemsId [] = ["product"=>30151,"qty"=>1]; //pusing an array with key 'product' & 'qty' to $ItemsId
```

**UPDATE**

This line

```
$orderGenerator->createOrder(array($ItemsId));
```

is not working because `$ItemsId` is already an array and you are putting this inside a new array with this `array($ItemsId)`. This will look like

```
Array([0] => 
     Array ([0] =>  
            Array(
                 [0] =>Array  ( [product] => 30143,[qty] => 1 ) 
                 [1] => Array ( [product] => 30144,[qty] => 2 ) 
                 [2] => Array ( [product] => 30145,[qty] => 3 ) 
                 [3] => Array ( [product] => 30146,[qty] => 4 ) 
                 [3] => Array ( [product] => 30147,[qty] => 5 ) 
            )
      )
)
```

But the expected array should look like

```
      Array ([0] =>  
             Array(
                   [0] =>Array  ( [product] => 30143,[qty] => 1 ) 
                   [1] => Array ( [product] => 30144,[qty] => 2 ) 
                   [2] => Array ( [product] => 30145,[qty] => 3 ) 
                   [3] => Array ( [product] => 30146,[qty] => 4 ) 
                   [3] => Array ( [product] => 30147,[qty] => 5 ) 
             )
       )
```

To overcome this issue just change

```
$orderGenerator->createOrder(array($ItemsId));
```

To

```
$orderGenerator->createOrder($ItemsId);
```

Comment: I have updated my question, can you please check it out?

Comment: I believe you are talking about this line `$orderGenerator->createOrder(array($ItemsId));`

Comment: how does `OrderGenerator()` looks like?

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/0iUbZpHU thanks so much for the help man!

Comment: Can you please help me out ?

Comment: it is doing what it's suppose to do. The issue is in your `_addProducts($product)` function

Comment: If you see the problem there, can you please help me out resolve it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120123/discussion-between-jonju-and-tony-stark).

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter that assures that both sub elements of the array share the same index. Like this:

```
$i = 0;

foreach(...) {
...
$ItemsId[$i]["product"] = $ProductId;             
$ItemsId[$i]["qty"] = $ProductQty;
...
$i++;
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question, can you please check it out?

Comment: Do you set `$ItemsId` in the method? In your example it is not set